# While creating model with factory, migration and resource controller for api inside new repository, conflict encounters in migration as below:

Tags: php, laravel

Used Command:

make:model Models/Test/TestApi -a

Error:

root@bb3433d4a92b:/var/www/nt-app-backend# php artisan make:model Models/Test/TestApi -a

Model created successfully.

Factory created successfully.

In ClassLoader.php line 571:

include(/var/www/nt-app-backend/vendor/composer/../../database/migrations/2022_05_06_151610_create_test_apis_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Please provide the context, which language or Framework are you using, where are you running these commands etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.